# How to put an image on a radio button with JavaScript and HTML5 after being validated

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I need to put an overlay image to a radio button after the question has been validated. If the answer is correct a tick above the radio button appears, and if it goes wrong a cross in the wrong answer and a tick in the right. 
All of these using JS and HTML.

The code already works, all I need is to put the images.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: You can use a relative positioning against the radio-button and Z-index in CSS to have both overlay images exactly on top of the radio-button and then selectively removing the `hidden` attribute from their styling.

Answer (score 0):

you need using z-index (css), and hidden. What is you code?

```css
 img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: -1; 
 }
```

```html
<img src="http://www.ultracurioso.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/2110.jpg" width="200">

<p>the image has a z-index of -1, your button/html code has overlay</p>

</body>
</html>
```